# wordpress migration broken links

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, migration

I am experiencing a problem with the wordpress migration.
I held my website on localhost beofre (xampp server in computer). It all worked fine so I decided to move it to a real domain. The website is http://www.cupavortex.ga .
I exported the database from phpMyAdmin in xampp, and imported it in the new database in the wordpress site. wp-config.php is already configured
The only thing working is the homepage and the buttons.
The images are not appearing.
And when I try to click on any link it redirects me to the old addresses (for example, when I try to click on “Desfasurare”, it redirects me to localhost/CupaVortex/desfasurare because that was the old link. I can’t acces wp-admin nor any administrative tools but phpMyAdmin and FileZilla.

Also, the site is hosted at 000webhost.com, and yes, I modified the mysql name to mysql4.000webhost.com from localhost, and replaced utf8mb4 with utf8 in order for everything to work. I just want to find out how to replace the links, I don’t really care about the images.. Theme used is Astrid.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you updated your database 'home' and 'site' url entries? This is done in wp_options, both need to be the new base url! After that, if thats the issue, you'll probably want to refresh your permalinks in the wp-admin settings section.

Answer (score 0):

Go Back to your old local host website for a sec.

Steps:

1. Go to Settings->Permalinks and set it to numeric values.
2. Check if you have not used a custom link inside the website for any images or post or anything. If you do then change it to the new numeric values from it.
3. Now just export the sql datasheet and website back up from old host to new host.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update ALL absolute links to posts, images, files etc.. by running the following plugin: "Velvet Blues Update url's"

What this will accomplish is (according to own personal experience and taken from plugin developer's page is)

FEATURES:

Users can choose to update links embedded in content, excerpts, or custom fields
Users can choose whether to update links for attachments
View how many items were updated

Last edited by Dimitar Coklev on Feb 18, 2018